# Improving script

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML page I have 9 paragraph items and 3 spans. If I click on the first three paragraph, I will load in the first span some webpage content. If I click on the second three paragraphs, I will load some webpage content in the second span. And so on for the last three paragraphs. I developed this code in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("p").click(function() {
                var myID = $(this)[0].id, where;

                if (myID == "p1" || myID == "p2" || myID == "p3") {
                    where = "span1";
                } else if (myID == "p4" || myID == "p5" || myID == "p6") {
                    where = "span2";
                } else {
                    where = "span3";
                }

                $("#"+where).load("GET", "hello.html",
                    function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
                        if (statusText == "error") alert("Errore "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText)
                    });

            });
        });

    </script>

    <p id="p1">Prova 1</p>
    <p id="p2">Prova 2</p>
    <p id="p3">Prova 3</p>

    <p id="p4">Prova 4</p>
    <p id="p5">Prova 5</p>
    <p id="p6">Prova 6</p>

    <p id="p7">Prova 7</p>
    <p id="p8">Prova 8</p>
    <p id="p9">Prova 9</p>

    <span id="span1">1</span>
    <span id="span2">2</span>
    <span id="span3">3</span>
```

It's working fine, but I would improve the section where I set the *where* var.
How could I do this? The smaller and flexible solution would be the best.

Comment: If it's working you should probably post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't know about that section. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a review of working code. It belongs on https://coderevew.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the *target* element information with `p` using `data-*` prefixed custom attributes which can be retrieved using `.data()` or `Element.dataset` property.

*HTML*

```
<p id="p1" data-target="#span1">Prova 1</p>
<p id="p4" data-target="#span2">Prova 4</p>
<p id="p7" data-target="#span3">Prova 7</p>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function() {
        var target = this.dataset.target;// $(this).data('target');
        $(target).load("GET", "hello.html",
            function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
                if (statusText == "error") alert("Errore "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText)
            });

    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $('.s').hide();
    var target = this.dataset.target; // $(this).data('target');
    $(target).show().text('Dummy Text ' + this.textContent)
  });
});
```

```css
.s {
  display: none;
  color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1" data-target="#span1">Prova 1</p>
<p id="p2" data-target="#span1">Prova 2</p>
<p id="p3" data-target="#span1">Prova 3</p>

<p id="p4" data-target="#span2">Prova 4</p>
<p id="p5" data-target="#span2">Prova 5</p>
<p id="p6" data-target="#span2">Prova 6</p>

<p id="p7" data-target="#span3">Prova 7</p>
<p id="p8" data-target="#span3">Prova 8</p>
<p id="p9" data-target="#span3">Prova 9</p>

<span class='s' id="span1">1</span>
<span class='s' id="span2">2</span>
<span class='s' id="span3">3</span>
```

Comment: Wow this is a really nice solution. I just have a question: is data-target valid in html's doctype as an attribute?

Comment: Awesome, just awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using data-attributes and unobstrusive way of doing this. Add common css-class and use that to attach single event and use data-attribute to tell which span to fill:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".clickMe").on("click", "p", function() {
     var $div = $(this).closest(".clickMe");
     $($div.data("target")).load("GET", "hello.html",
       function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
         if (statusText == "error") alert("Errore " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText)
       });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickMe" data-target="#span1">
  <p>Prova 1</p>
  <p>Prova 2</p>
  <p>Prova 3</p>
</div>

<div class="clickMe" data-target="#span2">
  <p>Prova 4</p>
  <p>Prova 5</p>
  <p>Prova 6</p>
</div>

<div class="clickMe" data-target="#span3">
  <p>Prova 7</p>
  <p>Prova 8</p>
  <p>Prova 9</p>
</div>

<span id="span1">1</span>
<span id="span2">2</span>
<span id="span3">3</span>
```

Note: Keep in mind that [span can only have phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

Comment: Thank you but I can't change HTML code. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data-target attribute in the html  and then on click just use that do load in the correct part

```js
loadContent = function( targetId ) {
  $("#" + targetId).text('fake load: ' + targetId);
}

$("p").on('click', function() {
  loadContent($(this).attr('data-target'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1" data-target="span1">Prova 1</p>
    <p id="p2" data-target="span1">Prova 2</p>
    <p id="p3" data-target="span1">Prova 3</p>

    <p id="p4" data-target="span2">Prova 4</p>
    <p id="p5" data-target="span2">Prova 5</p>
    <p id="p6" data-target="span2">Prova 6</p>

    <p id="p7" data-target="span3">Prova 7</p>
    <p id="p8" data-target="span3">Prova 8</p>
    <p id="p9" data-target="span3">Prova 9</p>

    <span id="span1">1</span>
    <span id="span2">2</span>
    <span id="span3">3</span>
```

You could argue that you're adding useless stuff in the html but I think it's nice knowing what element is linked to what just by looking at the html